# Can't use Set because a Core Data class is also called "Set"

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, set, foundation

I accidentally named a Core Data class Set. I can't change the class name because the model is already on CloudKit.

But now I can't use the Set struct. Is there anything I can do to use Set structs when I want to? Can I use NSSet instead? Will that impact anything considering I'm using Swift/SwiftUI?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify type of object like this:

```
class Set {}

let a = Swift.Set("1") //swift's Set instance
let b = Set() //your custom Set instance
let c = YourApp.Set() //your custom Set instance
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do Collection.Set. "Swift.Set" is what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice! Glad to help:)